# Why do the Horsemen attack people?

Tags: seraph-of-the-end

So, in Owari no Seraph, we have these weird monsters called "Horsemen of the Apocalypse" or "Horsemen of John", right?

Why do they attack people? What is their motive? Do they, for example, eat people for nutrition? Are they under the control of the vampires?

Comment: In the last episode I have seen, they say that Horsemen are not controled by vampires. They just want to kill humans.

Comment: As far as i have seen in the anime the horseman of john are basically independent creatures that just attack humans either for food or just because they want to, as (thus far) quoted in the anime they are not controlled by the vampires whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

No explanation is ever given as to why the Horsemen of the Apocalypse (also know as Horsemen of John) attack humans.

a quote -

> Horsemen only attack humans. Almost as if they were sent to cull the
>   world's bloated human population.

Source --Shinoa, Chapter 8, "Mitsuba's Squad

All of them attack humans and only humans, while they ignore every single other entity, they do not attack vampires or animals, with the exception of *one* Horseman of John, namely -

Spoiler alert -

> The special Horseman of John, summoned by [Abaddon](http://owarinoseraph.wikia.com/wiki/Abaddon) to destroy the army of vampires and humans